# How to filter data by date in a dataframe-list in R?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, filter

I have a large list of dataframes. It looks like that one below, its only much bigger.

```
V1 = c("1996-04-01", "1992-01-01", "1997-02-01", "1991-01-08", "1998-09-07")
V2 = runif(5, 10.0, 100.0)
V3 = runif(5, 10.0, 100.0)
V4 = runif(5, 10.0, 100.0)
V5 = runif(5, 10.0, 100.0)

df1 = data.frame (V1, V2, V3, V4, V5) 

V1 = c("2009-04-01", "1996-01-01", "1991-02-01", "1997-01-08", "2005-09-07")
V2 = runif(5, 10.0, 100.0)
V3 = runif(5, 10.0, 100.0)
V4 = runif(5, 10.0, 100.0)
V5 = runif(5, 10.0, 100.0)

df2 = data.frame (V1, V2, V3, V4, V5) 

V1 = c("2002-04-01", "1995-01-01", "1992-02-01", "1999-01-08", "2007-09-07")
V2 = runif(5, 10.0, 100.0)
V3 = runif(5, 10.0, 100.0)
V4 = runif(5, 10.0, 100.0)
V5 = runif(5, 10.0, 100.0)

df3 = data.frame (V1, V2, V3, V4, V5) 

dataframe_list = list(df1, df2, df3)
```

I want to remove rows with certain days. For example all years before 1995 and after 2000. I know how to do that in a dataframe, but how can addess all V1 columns in the dataframe-list? And how can I use the as.Date function? I got an error when I tried to do it. My try was:

```
for(i in 1:length(dataframe_list)){
  dataframe_list[[i]][,1]= as.Date(dataframe_list[[i]][,1],format="%Y-%m-%d")
  dataframe_list[dataframe_list[["V1"]] >= 1995, ]
  dataframe_list[dataframe_list[["V1"]] <= 2000, ]}
```

It doesnt work, does anyone know where the mistake could be? And does anyone know an easier solution?

Comment: Could you provide your example using `dput` so that we will manage to reproduce it easily? Also, please provide the error you get.

Comment: How does that work? I did dput (dataframe_list), but how does that help me to provide the data? Oh and, I dont have the example, I just made it up here. I only have the huge dataframe-list.

Comment: I have now an example in the post above!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to select on `i` your data frames:

```
for(i in 1:length(dataframe_list)){
  dataframe_list[[i]][,1]= as.Date(dataframe_list[[i]][,1],format="%Y-%m-%d")
  dataframe_list[[i]] = dataframe_list[[i]][year(dataframe_list[[i]][["V1"]]) >= 1995, ]
  dataframe_list[[i]] = dataframe_list[[i]][year(dataframe_list[[i]][["V1"]]) <= 2000, ]
}
dataframe_list
```

Also you need to use `year` to select the year part of your year.

**Better way to perform it: using data.table framework**

```
require(data.table)
dataframe_list = lapply(dataframe_list, setDT) # Transform data.frame into data.table
for(i in 1:length(dataframe_list)){
  dataframe_list[[i]][, V1 := as.Date(V1,format="%Y-%m-%d")]
  dataframe_list[[i]] = dataframe_list[[i]][year(V1) >= 1995 & year(V1) <= 2000, ]
}
```

Using data.table framework should make your computation way faster with big data.frames.

**Another version with lapply:**

Same code but easier to read. Define a filter function for a data.frame:

```
filter <- function(df){
  setDT(df)
  df[, V1 := as.Date(V1,format="%Y-%m-%d")]
  return(df[year(V1) >= 1995 & year(V1) <= 2000, ])
}
```

Apply it to your list:

```
lapply(dataframe_list, filter)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` from library `purrr` with filter :

```
df_list <- list(head(cars),head(cars),head(cars))

# [[1]]
# speed dist
# 1     4    2
# 2     4   10
# 3     7    4
# 4     7   22
# 5     8   16
# 6     9   10
# 
# [[2]]
# speed dist
# 1     4    2
# 2     4   10
# 3     7    4
# 4     7   22
# 5     8   16
# 6     9   10
# 
# [[3]]
# speed dist
# 1     4    2
# 2     4   10
# 3     7    4
# 4     7   22
# 5     8   16
# 6     9   10

library(purrr)
map(df_list, ~filter(.x,speed==7))

# [[1]]
# speed dist
# 1     7    4
# 2     7   22
# 
# [[2]]
# speed dist
# 1     7    4
# 2     7   22
# 
# [[3]]
# speed dist
# 1     7    4
# 2     7   22
```

Or in base R:

```
lapply(df_list,function(x) subset(x,speed==7))
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have dates, how can I transform them?

Comment: You should provide reproducible data, I'm bad at blind coding, but maybe `map(df_list, ~mutate(.x,V1 = as.Date(V1)) %>% filter(lubridate::year(V1) >= 1995, lubridate::year(V1) <= 2000)`

Comment: 1995 and 2000 are years (numeric values), not dates

Comment: Ok, hold on, I am providing an example! But its not the same as above.

Comment: The example is now above in my original post!